# Step by step getting start with facebook c# SDK for beginners

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I am new to the facebook c# SDK, want to get started but I'm confused.

Is there a step by step walk-through available for building an application with facebook integration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Writing your first FB app](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx)

You will also find [this](http://multitiered.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/getting-started-with-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/) and  [this](http://codesamplez.com/programming/facebook-api-access-token-using-c-sharp) useful for a start