# facebook OpenID

Tags: facebook, openid, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-login

By clicking a button of my page, should redirected to facebook login page. I'll give my username and password to login, it should return to my home page after authentication. I'm searched a lot to do this, couldn't get  any improvements. Plz help me to reach my destination.

My code:

```
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Extensions.SimpleRegistration; 
protected void OpenLogin_Click(object src, CommandEventArgs e) { 
OpenIdTextBox1.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
OpenIdTextBox1.LogOn();
} 
protected void OpenIdTextBox1_LoggedIn(object sender, OpenIdEventArgs e){
var sreg = e.Response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
if (sreg != null){
var email = sreg.Email;var postalCode = sreg.PostalCode;
}
}
```

Comment: What code,SDK you are using for login page?

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty;using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Extensions.SimpleRegistration;                 protected void OpenLogin_Click(object src, CommandEventArgs e) { OpenIdTextBox1.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();OpenIdTextBox1.LogOn();} protected void OpenIdTextBox1_LoggedIn(object sender, OpenIdEventArgs e){var sreg = e.Response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();if (sreg != null){var email = sreg.Email;var postalCode = sreg.PostalCode;}}

Comment: Are you using Javascript-SDK for login or C#SDK?

Answer (score 0):

See this procedures links. I am unable to configure what's your problem.

1. [facebook c# sdk getting started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720023/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-getting-started)
2. [Step by step getting start with facebook c# SDK for beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136693/step-by-step-getting-start-with-facebook-c-sharp-sdk-for-beginners)
3. http://multitiered.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/getting-started-with-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/
4. [Integrating facebook login and facebook c# SDK - NOT a facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047743/integrating-facebook-login-and-facebook-c-sharp-sdk-not-a-facebook-app)
5. http://weblogs.asp.net/kon/archive/2010/11/15/getting-started-with-facebook-c-sdk.aspx

Comment if you are not getting though anything, about which link(your procedure) you have used.

## Update:

Facebook is not openid provider. You can use facebook-connect for the same.

See following links:

1. [Is Facebook an OpenID provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827997/is-facebook-an-openid-provider)
2. [Is facebook an openid provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045296/is-facebook-an-openid-provider)
3. [What is the "openid" url of facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264266/what-is-the-openid-url-of-facebook)
4. [facebook with openid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593620/facebook-with-openid)

Comment: I'm using my Google Username and password as Open-ID to get logged into my own website. The C# code i've posted above is helping me to do this work successfully. Instead of using google i need to login using my facebook username and password as Open-ID. See this link http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/OpenIDProviderList , it gives me the Open-ID endpoint for corresponding providers. Due to my research i got that facebook doesn't've endpoint. It has an unique way to implement Open-ID concept. Plz help me to reach my goal.